# Can't align text horizontally in ReactNative UI

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently working on my React Native's app UI and an alignment problem is killing me: I can't get my text box and text input's texts aligned horizontally.

[image: Misaligned items]

Here is an excerpt of the render for a line:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.line}>
                <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Player name:</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textBox}
                    onChangeText={(playerNameState) => this.setState({playerNameState })}
                    value={this.state.playerNameState} />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

And here are the styles I use (background colour is just for boundingbox reference:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
},
line: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 5,
    height: 50
},
textLabel: {
    height: 50,
    fontSize: 18,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    alignItems: 'center'
},
textBox: {
    color: 'grey',
    height: 50,
    fontSize: 18,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    flexGrow: 1,
    alignItems: 'center'
}
```

I *think* I shouldn't be needing as many alaignItems, but I just wanted to show you what I tried. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap those Text(Input)-Components into Views and it should work:

```
render() {
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.line}>
            <View style={styles.textLabel}>
              <Text>Player name:</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.textBox}>
              <TextInput
                onChangeText={(playerNameState) => this.setState({playerNameState })}
                value={this.state.playerNameState} />
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
);}
```

You can also add justifyContent: 'center' to styles.textBox & textLabel to align the content vertically.

Comment: View doesn't have fontSize as a style prop. Just switching over the styles is likely to cause problems.

Comment: You are right! The View should serve as wrapper container to align items or change the background etc. Style props like fontSize should remain at the child component.